# Examples of holomorphic Killing vector fields on compact Kahler manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm looking for concrete examples of compact Kahler manifolds that admit global holomorphic Killing vector fields.

The only examples I can think of so far are quite trivial:
(i) CP^N with the Fubini study metric;
(ii) complex tori with the Euclidean metric.

Are there any other examples?

Comment: For any complex reductive group $G$, take a homogeneous projective variety $G/P$ with a metric invariant by some compact subgroup $K$ of $G$. Then any element of $\mathrm{Lie}(K)$ defines a holomorphic Killing field.

Comment: In case it helps you to know, any Killing vector field on a compact Kahler manifold is automatically holomorphic.